Looking for 80s/90s film with a "fountain of youth" in the woods and an immortal tortoise on a road
It was a film I watched in the 90s, not very well known and with live actors (not a cartoon). It was in English language, probably American.
I can barely remember any of it, apart from there being a well or a spring in some woods that made anyone who drank it immortal and a tortoise who had had the pleasure was hit by a car at the end - to little effect, as you can imagine.
I have no idea what the main plot-line was. The fact that I can only remember those points probably means it wasn't too great (at least to an under-10) but I need to know.

Oops, sorry everyone - if your curiosity was piqued, I just found out that it was Tuck Everlasting (1981). Feel a bit of an eejit but at least it wasn't the remake... obvious, much?
